# Custom routing issue in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a default route in my ASP.NET MVC application, that looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default",
"{action}/{menu}/{lang},
new {controller="Web" action = "Page", menu = UrlParameter.Optional, lang = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Everything works fine in the local development environment. But it breaks after deployment in IIS. Links don't work any more, and I cannot navigate to the default page.

Comment: How are you generating those links? Are you using heleprs? Are you javascript (if so, have you by some chances hardcoded your links instead of using helpers)?

Comment: They are generated using helpers. But the links are note the only problem. Routing fails completely. When I navigate to the root it says: No route in the route table matches the supplied values